# Displaying a bundle of HTML files with POCO 1.9.4 configured server

Tags: html, networking, embedded-server

I am using POCO 1.9.4, configured as a server. I am trying the sample code `"HTTPFormServer"` from Poco libraries. I am able to display the index.html page when queried from browser. But I couldnt navigate to other html pages from `index.html` page (placed in same directory as index file).

I have modified the `sendFile()` of the handle request method as shown below. It displays index.html page when queried from browser (using `"http://localhost:9980/"`). But when I click any buttons at index page, it doesnt navigate to other pages I need help in understanding how to display a bundle of html files placed at a directory (starting with `index.html` in it).

```
    void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
    {
        Application& app = Application::instance();
        app.logger().information("Request from " + request.clientAddress().toString());
        app.logger().information("URI " + request.getURI()); 

        MyPartHandler partHandler;
        HTMLForm form(request, request.stream(), partHandler);

        response.setChunkedTransferEncoding(true);
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        /*std::ostream& ostr = */ response.sendFile("html1\\index.html", "text");
#if 0
        ostr <<
            "<html>\n"
            "<head>\n"
            "<title>POCO Form Server Sample</title>\n"
            "</head>\n"
                        "<html>\n"
#endif
        }
```